# vertx IllegalArgumentException: No message codec for type - how to create a consumer for a custom type

Tags: exception, vert.x, event-bus

I have a verticle that creates an event bus consumer as follows:

```
    public void start() {
        vertx.eventBus().consumer(ADDRESS_REQUEST, this::handleRequestMessage);

    }

    private void handleRequestMessage(Message<VWApiConversation> msg) {

       VWApiConversation conversation = msg.body();

    }
```

But when sending a message to this address :

```
 vertx.eventBus().send(VehicleStateCoordinatorVerticle.ADDRESS_REQUEST, conversation, deliveryOptions, res -> {
```

...

I get the error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No message codec for type: class com.vulog.vwgateway.model.VWApiConversation
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vert.x supports serializing JVM primitives, `Buffer`s, and `JsonObject`s by default. for other custom types you'll need to write your own [MessageCodec](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/eventbus/MessageCodec.html).

here's some documentation that might be of help:

- the official [docs](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_the_theory) has a few notes about this. the section titled "Types of messages" will be of particular interest to you.
- [here](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/blob/master/core-examples/src/main/java/io/vertx/example/core/eventbus/messagecodec/util/CustomMessageCodec.java) is a sample `MessageCodec` implementation. (not shown in this snippet is registration of the codec via `EventBus.registerCodec()`.)

for my taste i've always used `JsonObject` as the messaging medium (as my setups have enabled me to). seems like a hassle to write custom (de)serializers for every domain type.